# Git autocomplete stopped working in Oh My ZSH

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

Help!

My git autocomplete stopped working in Oh My ZSH.  It was working, but now it is now.  I'm not sure what changed, so I'm hoping someone can help me track down the problem.  I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling but no luck,

```
Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
plugins=(git)
```